# rsyslog Email On SSH/SFTP Login Fails

Tags: email, exim, rsyslog, courier

I have tried the following on my Nginx server, but do not get any emails upon SSH (or SFTP) login. I put this code in `/etc/rsyslog.d/notify.conf` and have ensured this file is being called by `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

```
$ModLoad ommail
$ActionMailSMTPServer example.com
$ActionMailFrom example@example.com
$ActionMailTo example@gmail.com
$template mailSubject,"User logged into %hostname%"
$template mailBody,"RSYSLOG Alert\r\nmsg='%msg%'"
$ActionMailSubject mailSubject
$ActionExecOnlyOnceEveryInterval 60
if $msg contains 'session opened for user' then :ommail:;mailBody
```

I have also tried the following line instead of the last line above:

```
if $msg contains 'Accepted password for' then :ommail:;mailBody
```

I have tried a variation of hostnames for the SMTPserver with the two different scenarios above including:

```
hostname.domain.com, 127.0.0.1, [server-ip]
```

I have even tried commenting out the entire `$ActionMailSMTPServer` line.

I can't figure out why rsyslog mail is not working. Email via bash works just fine (e.g. `mail email@gmail.com`). What am I doing wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in addition to Exim and Courier.